# Android Studio - New project uses over 20MB of memory

Tags: android, memory

If I create a blank new project and run it, it uses 23MB of memory.

If I add one 540x960 png image to the background of the layout, it uses 47MB of memory.

If I add an image button with a background image on it, it uses 64MB of memory.

This continues to go on if I add things, and this is way too much. On the app I am currently working on, I have memory used at between 180-210MB of memory. I figured there was something wrong I was doing with loading the images, so I ended up putting them all on imgur, and loading them in with Glide. This reduced the memory by a small amount, and also doesn't explain why a new blank project would use 23MB.

I thought there might be some kind of setting, but I re-installed with default settings and am still getting the problem.

Comment: "it uses 23MB of memory" -- please explain what you are using to measure this.

Comment: How big is your button's background image?

Comment: I was using the Memory tab at the bottom under Android Monitor.

The buttons background size was about the same as the background.  970x360 i think.

Sled's answer below worked to bring the memory down to 26MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced a similar issue when I put the drawable in the wrong resolution folder, especially the standard "drawable" folder is a pitfall since it is assumed to contain the image in "mdpi" resolution, so the image gets upscaled like crazy on xxhdpi devices.

Here's a simple test to figure it out, move the images into a folder called "drawable-nodpi" and check for the memory consumption.

Then make sure to provide the image in the right resolution in their dedicated folders, and avoid the "drawable" folder for images, just use it for xml drawables.

What basically happens is if you put your "540x960" image in to the standard drawable folder, it is assumed to be mdpi, if you view it on a relatively modern "xxhdpi" devices the image gets upscaled by a factor of 3 e.g it will be "1620x2880" and therefore consume much more memory.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: This worked, thank you! It brought the memory usage down to 26MB, only adding 3MB of memory for these two images.

Seeing as how in my actual project, I have 50+ images to use, I feel like it still is going to be using a lot more memory than intended. Do you know if 23MB on a blank project is normal?

Comment: don't worry about the 26mb, the images won't be an issue since memory is recycled, when you use a ListView/GridView etc. In a long list of images only the ones visible or close to visible will be actively kept in RAM. Just make sure you provide the images in the right resolution for the right devices i.e you don't want to show that 540x960 image on a ldpi device for example. Premature optimization is the root of all evil ;)

Comment: depends, if all images are visible i.e the relative layout just fills the screen then it's ok but if the relative layout is much bigger than the screen, i.e scrolls then it's a bad choice because the scroll view alone won't recycle the images. Maybe you could use a GridView and design the adapter so that it will return empty elements at certain places so that you can get the hexagon.

Comment: Okay, I didnt know I could change the grid view in that way. I will look up how to do that.